# Как изменить владельца таблицы в базе?

Tags: postgresql

Не могу изменить владельца таблицы searches c postgres на flautdb в PostgreSQL. Делаю запрос:

```
ALTER TABLE flaut.searches OWNER TO flautdb;
ALTER TABLE public.searches OWNER TO flautdb;
ALTER TABLE searches OWNER TO flautdb;
```

Ничего из этого не работает. Хотя в документации PSQL сказано, что, мол, просто укажите название таблицы. А ничего подобного:

> ERROR:  relation "searches" does not exist

UDP: таблица searches существует в базе flaut. База flaut принадлежит роли flautdb, а вот таблица searches внутри неё принадлежит postgres. Если запросить таблицы под ролью flaut, то всё нормально:

```
          List of relations
 Schema |   Name   | Type  |  Owner
--------+----------+-------+----------
 public | searches | table | postgres
(1 row)
```

А вот если запрашивать под ролью postgres уже нельзя - она не видит таблицу. А в контексте базы flaut под ролью flautdb изменять ничего не могу.

> flaut=> ALTER TABLE searches OWNER TO flautdb;
>
> ERROR:  must be owner of relation searches

Comment: PostgreSQL пишет вам, что нет такой таблицы. В выводе команды `\dt` она есть?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev подправил вопрос.